# Sublime form command line terminal

Tags: sublimetext2

I have set up `sublime` open from my command line, but it is not opening the file that I am in.
For example, if I am in `test.html` and enter `subl .` in the command line `sublime` will open, but it is blank.

How do I make it open the file that I am currently in?

Comment: How are you "in" a file?

Comment: I suspect that you are not, in fact, "in" a file. A shell can be "in" a directory, this is called the working directory. But you cannot edit a directory with sublime. Maybe try `subl [filename]` instead of `subl .`?

Answer (score 1):

`subl .` will open the folder you're in in St. You can either open only one file `subl file.html` or open the folder, and then display the side bar (from memory: cmd+k, b (ctrl for windows/linux), or somewhere in view menu I guess (not in front of a computer right now). 
Hope that helps.

After verification, it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (for Mac, I guess you just replace <kbd>⌘</kbd> bt <kbd>ctrl</kbd>). Or View->Side Bar->Show Side Bar.

Also, if ST was completely closed before, it happens (not sure if it is systematic) that you have to run the command twice for the file to really open.